# SQL Server JSON group

Tags: sql, arrays, json, sql-server

I'm trying to transform my table to JSON

My table:

```sql
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #tmp
CREATE TABLE #tmp(AnalyticGoodsT CHAR(6), date SMALLDATETIME)

INSERT INTO #tmp(AnalyticGoodsT, date)
VALUES ('000001', '20230424'), ('000002', '20230424'), ('000003', '20230424'), ('000004', '20230424')
```

Required JSON format(i'm trying to group rows by date):

```json
[
  {
    "Date": "24.04.2023",
    "bk": [
      "000001",
      "000002",
      "000003",
      "000004"
    ]
  }
]
```

The only way to do this that I found is this

```sql
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(x, '{"id":',''), '"}','"') FROM 
    (SELECT TOP 10 
        Date=CONVERT(varchar,date,104), 
        (SELECT DISTINCT id=AnalyticGoodsT FROM #tmp a2 
        WHERE a1.date=a2.date
        FOR JSON path) AS bk 
    FROM #tmp a1 
    GROUP BY date 
    FOR JSON PATH) a(x)
```

But it seems to me that this method is completely wrong.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) Post the JSON you expect as *text*, not an image.

Comment: May i ask you, why do you want to make a sql table returned as json ?

Comment: Unfortunately, SQL Server's only JSON array function ([`JSON_ARRAY`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/json-array-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)) expects a list of scalar expression (`JSON_ARRAY('abc',1,'def',2)`) and does not have an aggregate equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, SQL Server does not have `JSON_AGG`. You need to use a combination of `STRING_AGG` `JSON_QUERY` and `STRING_ESCAPE`

```sql
SELECT
  Date = CONVERT(nvarchar(10), t.date, 104),
  bk = JSON_QUERY(N'[' + STRING_AGG(N'"' + STRING_ESCAPE(t.AnalyticGoodsT, 'json') + N'"', N',') + N']')
FROM #tmp t
GROUP BY
  t.date
FOR JSON PATH;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/GqpqjIR9)

`STRING_ESCAPE` is necessary to escape any invalid JSON characters, and `JSON_QUERY` is necessary to prevent double-escaping.

Answer (score 1):

You can only simplify your statement. I don't think, that you can build a dynamic JSON array of scalar values, so you need a text-based approach:

- Build the JSON array using a combination of `STRING_AGG()`, `CONCAT()` and `STRING_ESCAPE()` (to escapes possible special characters).
- Wrap the generated array with `JSON_QUERY()` to prevent the escaping of the generated JSON array. As is explained in the documentation, *... JSON_QUERY returns a valid JSON fragment. As a result, FOR JSON doesn't escape special characters in the JSON_QUERY return value*.
- Return the expected JSON with `FOR JSON AUTO`.

T-SQL:

```
SELECT 
   CONVERT(varchar(10), [date], 104) AS [Date], 
   JSON_QUERY(
      CONCAT('[', STRING_AGG('"' + STRING_ESCAPE(AnalyticGoodsT, 'json') + '"', ','), ']')
   ) AS [bk]
FROM #tmp
GROUP BY [date]
FOR JSON AUTO
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using `JSON_QUERY` and `STRING_AGG` to contruct the bk array and `FOR JSON PATH` as follows :

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT date,
         JSON_QUERY('["' + STRING_AGG( AnalyticGoodsT, '","') + '"]') as bk
          
  FROM #tmp
  group by date
) AS s
FOR JSON PATH
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/9iztxPMy)

Comment: That isn't quite right; your JSON array is inside double quotes.

Comment: Fixed using `JSON_QUERY`, thanks @ThomA